# How to - Write a program to check if a number has at least one equal adjacent number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already did some research but i cant find the solution or help for my doubt.

Im doing coursera python course, and i have an optional exercise that i not figuring out the solution.

So the exercise is a kinda simple, "Write a program that receave a number and check if the receave number has, at least, one equal adjacent number." EX: 12256 (adjacent number), 123456 (doesnt have adjacent number) Only using while loop and/or if statment. So list and lens aren't allowed to use.

I did like this:

```
    x = int(input("Number: "))

    while (x != 0):
        resto = x % 10
        x = (x - resto) //10
    if resto == resto:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("no")
```

The question, here, is that i not figuring out how to evaluate my if statement to false.

Thanks in advance for any help =)

Comment: `resto == resto` will always be `True`... and what is an 'equal adjacent number'? equal in what sense?

Comment: Could you post an 'expected output' with a certain input? This will help clarify your question

Comment: Can you use [try](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) statements?

Comment: only while and if. I mean i only learned while and if statement in the course until now. So i assume i only can use them. Is getting annoying for me puiff lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a version that is close to yours. note that the `else` statement of the `while` loop is only executed if the while loop terminates normally - not via `break`.

```
num = int(input('enter number: '))

prev = num % 10
num //= 10

while num:
    cur = num % 10
    if cur == prev:
        print('yes')
        break
    prev = cur
    num //= 10
else:
    print('no')
```

you put your `if` statement **after** the while loop - it should be inside it. and it should compare `resto` to something else (`cur` and `prev` in my code).

Comment: Haaa i got it now. Well done and thanks for the easy explanation =) and thanks everyone too for the given help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check each digit of a number, don't convert it into an `int`. Then you can test each digit:

```
num = input('enter number: ')
index = 0
prev = None
while index < len(num):
    if num[index] = prev:
        print('yes!')
        break
    prev = num[index]
    index += 1
else:
    print('no!') # no same adjacent digit
```

The else clause executes if the while loop terminates without encountering `break`. If there is no break, then there were no adjacent same digits. I haven't included any type checking to make sure the input is a number

Comment: Ah yes I shall refactor.

Answer (score 0):

You say

> The question, here, is that i not figuring out how to evaluate my if statement to false.

The solution to this is

```
if resto == (x % 10):
```

instead of

```
if resto == resto:
```

Think about it: is there *any possible scenario* where `resto` is not going to be equal to itself?

Comment: I already did this change and always returns false even if the inserted number has an adjacent